# Ninja and PDB file size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, ninja, pdb-files

I am building software for Windows using MSVC compiler. CMake is used as a project generator that supports two types of build Visual Studio and Ninja. It is a quite large and proprietary project thus I cannot share many details.

The problem is a difference in .pdb debugging symbols files that are generated as a result of this build.
When Visual Studio generator is used the resulted .pdb file is 2.5GB
When Ninja generator is used the file is whooping 4.2GB and sometimes goes 5+GB
Since the limit for the possible .pdb files size is 4GB according to my research, linking of the target when using Ninja is failing.

There is a possible workaround exist:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pdb-limit-of-4-gib-is-likely-to-be-a-problem-in-a/904784

However, this is just patching the problem and not really solving it. The question is why Ninja all of a sudden generates such enormous PDB file sizes? Is there a way to prevent this? What would be the root cause for this?

Comment: Have you compared the compiler & linker switches passed by VS builds vs the Ninja build?

Comment: Yes, I double-checked, flags are the same.

Comment: Can you add the flags and the command lines to the question that are used for Visual Studio cl and for ninja? That would help to give some sound advice to cut the size of the PDB. To extract this information you may need to run the compilation with an additonal argument `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` or add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt.